# Find depth difference between two nodes in a tree without going all the way up to the root

Tags: graph, tree, binary, lowest-common-ancestor

I Came across a question I couldn't figure out.

> Assume A binary tree, where each node has a pointer to its parent, and two children.
> We receive input for r, p,q ( root, and two nodes from the tree) and we want to find the depth difference between p and q, Without Traversing all the way up to the root.
>
> #### Limitations and Assumptions:
>
> - No memory usage (meaning no arrays, variables are ok)
> - Assume the nodes Lowest Common Ancestor isn't the root (and for simplicity let's assume the LCA is far from the root in Big-O notation Terms.

Just to clarify -
Basically, the question is how do we figure out the depth difference without going all the way up to the root, and without memory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, the question is how do we figure out the depth difference without going all the way up to the root...

It isn't saying that you cannot traverse all the way up to the root. It just says that the final outcome may not be the root.

First, define a function to determine the *depth* of a node (pseudo code):

```py
function depthOf(r, p):
    depth = 0
    temp = p
    while curr is not r:
        depth++
        temp = temp.parent
    return depth
```

Simply call this function for both nodes, and take the difference.

As an additional feature, you can use this information to find the Lowest Common Ancestor:

Use the depth difference to walk up from the deepest node of the two up until you are at the same depth as the other. From then on walk upwards from both nodes in tandem, until you arrive at the same node from both sides:

```py
function least(r, p, q)
    diff = depthOf(r, p) - depthOf(r, q)  # The answer
    # In order to find least common ancestor, continue as follows:
    while diff > 0:  # p is deeper than q
        p = p.parent
        diff--
    while diff < 0:  # q is deeper than p
        q = q.parent
        diff++
    while p is not q:
        p = p.parent
        q = q.parent
    return p
```

Comment: Hi trincot, 

Thanks for the reply, im afraid that is not what i was looking for.
This is a solution for the LCA problem when you are determining the depth of each node by going all the way up to the root for each of them.
My question is how can this be done without traversing all the way up.

Comment: My point is that there is nothing in the challenge that says you cannot go all the way up. NB: I only provided the LCA solution as an addition... it is not the core of my answer. If you have a link to and quote of the actual challenge, please add it as such in your question. That will possibly clarify what the restrictions are.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply!
I Updated the question to clarify that specification.


But that is precisely my question, assuming the distance from LCA to Root is not O(1) then How can this be done *Without* travesing all the way up to the root.

Comment: It is not possible to guarantee that you will not go up to the root with any algorithm. You might just bump into it. I don't understand this restriction. Unless you have a *guarantee* that the LCA is at most K levels above the nodes *p* and *q*... where K is an input to the algorithm.

Comment: As I added to the question above. Let's assume the LCA is Atleast O(f(n)) steps away from the node when O(long)>f(n)>O(sqrt(logn)) - Some f that is not O(1) and is a function of n.
In other words lets assume the LCA is far from the root in a significant distance.

Comment: You do realise that unless the tree is abnormally unbalanced, that a path to the root is just O(logn), right? For a binary tree with one million nodes, the expected distance from leaf to root is in the order of 20.